# combine multiple sql statements

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

I currently have a working set of queries from my database but I can not come up with a way to turn these into 1 query for efficiency and to keep the data correlated to each other. The testrecord table contains 1 row of data for each test run including the siteid code which is the primary key for site table which contains the name of the company.

```
SELECT COUNT(`teststatus`) AS `total tested` 
FROM `testrecord`;

SELECT COUNT(`teststatus`) AS `passed` 
FROM `testrecord` 
WHERE `teststatus` = 0;

SELECT `companyname` 
FROM `site` 
INNER JOIN testrecord ON `site`.`siteid` = `testrecord`.`siteid` 
GROUP BY `site`.`siteid`;
```

I'm looking for a single query that returns the basic format below:

```
total tested | passed | companyname
-------------+--------+-----------
    76       |   68   | company1
   156       |  150   | company2
```

I'm using MySql and running the queries from my php website.

Comment: Does sql union help? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT s.companyname, count(*) as total_tested,
       SUM( tr.teststatus = 0 ) as passed
FROM site s INNER JOIN
     testrecord tr
     ON tr.siteid = s.siteid
GROUP BY s.siteid;
```

The above assumes that you are using MySQL (the backticks suggest MySQL).  If not, then the `SELECT` should look like:

```
SELECT s.companyname, count(*) as total_tested,
       SUM(CASE WHEN tr.teststatus = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as passed
```

Comment: thanks so much it worked after 1 minor tweak line 3 should read FROM site s INNER JOIN.  i've been researching all day for this answer, your a big help!